# Calculating scheme for a particular solution of a linear differential equation (UCM)

Tags: tikz-pgf, booktabs, tabularray, tikzmark, systeme

The following is calculating scheme for a particular solution of a linear differential equation via the undetermined coefficient method. The result is quite okay, using the library `tikzmark` of TikZ.

I am expecting better (in your opinion) codes, with TikZ or just with LaTeX. Using TikZ seems too heavy and lengthy. Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y^*    &\tikzmarknode{e1}{=} Ate^{2t}+Be^{-2t}\\
(y^*)' &\tikzmarknode{e2}{=} A(1+2t)e^{2t}-2Be^{-2t}\\
(y^*)''&\tikzmarknode{e3}{=} A(4+4t)e^{2t}+4Be^{-2t}\\[3mm]
1      &\tikzmarknode{e4}{=} 4A-5A=-A\\
1      &\tikzmarknode{e5}{=} 4B+10B+6B=20B
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[nodes={magenta,left}] 
(e1)+(-2,0) node{$6\quad \times$}
(e2)+(-2,0) node{$-5\quad \times$}
(e3)+(-2,0) node{$1\quad \times$}
(e4)+(-2,0) node{$e^{2t}$}
(e5)+(-2,0) node{$e^{-2t}$}
;
\path 
(e3)--(e4) coordinate[midway] (X)
(X)--+(-3,0) coordinate (A)
(X)--+(4,0) coordinate (B)
(e1)+(-1.5,.3) coordinate (C)
(e5)+(-1.5,-.3) coordinate (D)
;
\draw[magenta] (A)--(B) (C)--(D);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: If you have better calculating scheme, please share!

Update: It's my blackboard-chalk style in teaching, not in writing textbooks. I find that it is easier for students.

[image]

The situation in the question is from answers of a final ODE examination. https://www.overleaf.com/read/srpbvhvddzwx

Comment: Not an answer, really, but I do not see the point of using some scheme for this. Why not just write things out? Something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aETdv.png).

Comment: @mickep It's my blackboard-chalk style in teaching. Please see my update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible alternative with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{colspec={rrrcl},
  vline{3} = {magenta},
  hline{4} = {magenta},
  column{1} = {font={\color{magenta}}, rightsep=0pt},
  column{2} = {font={\color{magenta}}, leftsep=0pt, rightsep+=4pt},
  column{3} = {leftsep+=4pt, rightsep=0pt},
  column{4} = {colsep=2pt},
  column{5} = {leftsep=0pt},
  row{3} = {belowsep+=4pt},
  row{4} = {abovesep+=4pt}
  }
6 & \times & y^* & = & Ate^{2t}+Be^{-2t}\\
-5 & \times & (y^*)' & = & A(1+2t)e^{2t}-2Be^{-2t}\\
1 & \times & (y^*)''& = & A(4+4t)e^{2t}+4Be^{-2t}\\
&e^{2t} &1 & = & 4A-5A=-A\\
&e^{-2t} & 1 & = & 4B+10B+6B=20B\\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a nice solution (`hline`, `vline`) with `tabularray`. I have a quick look at its documentation, and be impressive with some features like linking with `booktabs`, ... https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf