# Solving systems by reduction

Tags: arrays, cases

In LaTeX, when I solve systems by reduction, I like to put the numbers by which I multiply the equations in front of the key of the system, how would this be done?

[image]

I'm able to create the system without the numbers in front as:

```
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
2x + y = 5 \\
-5x + 3y =2
\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
-10x - 5y = -25 \\
10x - 6y = -4
\end{array}
```

But the rest I can't do it.

Comment: Are you able to create the system without the numbers in front?  Could you edit the code for that into your post?  That would give us something to start from.

Comment: @Teepeemm I've edited the post. Thanks

Comment: I suggest using a recent package `tabularray` https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray Also see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670019/140722

Answer (score 1):

Using the `matrix` library in `tikz` should do the trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,math,matrix,positioning,shadows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix
        {
        \node {$(-5) \: \cdot$}; &[1mm] \node(eq1) {$2x + y = 5$};  &[5mm]  \node(eq1a) {$-10x - 5y = -25$};    \\
        \node {$(-2) \: \cdot$}; & \node(eq2) {$-5x + 3y = 2$}; &   \node(eq2a) {$10x -6y = -4$};\\
        };
    \draw[thick,blue,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] ([xshift=-2.5mm,yshift=2mm]eq1.west) -- ([yshift=-2mm]eq2.west);
    \draw[thick,blue,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] ([yshift=2mm]eq1a.west) -- node[left] {$\Rightarrow$} ([xshift=-2.3mm,yshift=-2mm]eq2a.west);
    \draw[thick,blue] ([xshift=-15mm]eq2a.south) --+ (3,0);
    \node(eq3) [below=of eq2a,yshift=8mm] {$-11y = -29$};
    \node [right=of eq3,xshift=-7mm] {$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \quad y = \frac{-29}{-11}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: math equation]

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYMs.png) ([code](https://pastebin.com/raw/XAaHnpw1))?

Comment: We did those changes at the same time @Werner . Made a few typo's with signs too, so changed them as well. I updated my answer and picture. Thanks.

Comment: Your system doesn't align by the variables `x` and `y` across` the equations. See my output above.

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much. Just one thing: more space could be left in front of and behind the \Rightarrow that separates the two systems? I have tried adding \ \ but the arrow has been put in the middle of the two equations in front.