# How to produce the following equations

Tags: amsmath

[image]

Let the equations be aligned at $=$ sign

Comment: Do you also want to perform alignmnent on the `x^3`,`x^2`, `x`, and scalar terms?

Comment: BTW, you're getting down votes because you threw up an image and left us to do all the work.  Did you create this image?  You could have posted its code.  Otherwise, you could have posted your best attempt.

Comment: I didn't downvote...

Comment: a suggestion is using `tabularray` package https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularray/0 ; also see an example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670019/140722

Comment: I'm a new contributor,still learning on how to post a question

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you would want to perform alignment not only on the `=` symbols but on the `x^3`, `x^2`, `x`, and scalar terms as well, the following, `array`-based, solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for mathbin and mathrel objects
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{*{4}{rC} l}
y & = &  x^3 & + & 3x^2 & - &   4x & - & 12    \\ 
0 & = & -x^3 & - & 3x^2 & + & 3.5x & + & 10.5  \\
\midrule
y & = &      &   &      & - & 0.5x & - & 1.5 
\end{array}
%
\begin{array}{c}
  \left.\begin{array}{c} 
    \null \\ \null 
  \end{array}\right\} + \\
  \addlinespace 
  \null 
\end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 5):

Using the [systeme](https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/generic/systeme/systeme_fr.pdf) package, I have this
[image]

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\title{stack tex equation}
\author{Equation}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\sysdelim.\}\systeme{y=x^3 + 3x^2 - 4x - 12, y = -x^3 - 3x^2 + 3.5x + 10.5} \quad{+}}{y = -\frac{1}{2}x - 1.5}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

That may look well and sufficient, especially if you need to do more than one system like this.